# Navigation property not showing in scaffold with code first model in EF5 MVC4

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have the following model for an article.

```
public class Article
{
    [Key]
    public int ArticleId { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Title is required."), MaxLength(80)]
    public string Title { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Body is required.")]
    public string Body { get; set; }

    public DateTime Time { get; set; }

    public int AuthorId { get; set; }

    // Navigation properties
    public virtual UserProfile Author { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Tag> Tags { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Comment> Comments { get; set; }
}
```

The `UserProfile` is an extendend version of the default in the MVC4 standard project.

Now, in my scaffolded controller/view, there is no way to enter the `Author`.

My database (MySQL) contains a field with named `Author_UserId` of type `int`.

**What is wrong?**

Also, is it really necessary for the author to be referenced both via the navigation property *and* the `AuthorId`

Answer (score 0):

It's not common to use 2 the same Foreign keys of a specific table at any table. Such this interpreted as data redundancy. To solve the problem without any redundancy, i suggest bellow model to you:

```
public class Article
{
    [Key]
    public int ArticleId { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Title is required."), MaxLength(80)]
    public string Title { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Body is required.")]
    public string Body { get; set; }

    public DateTime Time { get; set; }

    public int AuthorId { get; set; }//determine name of foreign key here of type primary key of navigatable table

    // Navigation properties
    [ForeignKey("AuthorId")]
    public virtual UserProfile Author { get; set; }//column with name 'AuthorId'
    public virtual ICollection<Tag> Tags { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Comment> Comments { get; set; }
}
```

Solution above, used to self naming navigation property foreign key. 
I wish be useful.

Comment: I have implemented your suggestions, but I still get no `Author` under `Create`.

Comment: Make sure you are using DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges of EF to sense changes.

Comment: I did the test on a clean project and db.